# How to delete certain words from a variable or a list python

Tags: python, text, replace, stop-words

```
common_words = set(['je', 'tek', 'u', 'još', 'a', 'i', 'bi',
            's', 'sa', 'za', 'o', 'kojeg', 'koju', 'kojom', 'kojoj',
            'kojega', 'kojemu', 'će', 'što', 'li', 'da', 'od', 'do',
            'su', 'ali', 'nego', 'već', 'no', 'pri', 'se', 'li',
            'ili', 'ako', 'iako', 'bismo', 'koji', 'što', 'da', 'nije',
            'te', 'ovo', 'samo', 'ga', 'kako', 'će', 'dobro',
            'to', 'sam', 'sve', 'smo', 'kao'])
all = []


for (item_content, item_title, item_url, fetch_date) in cursor:
             #text = "{}".format(item_content)
             text= item_content
             text= re.sub('[,.?";:\-!@#$%^&*()]', '', text)
             text = text.lower()
             #text = [w for w in text if not w in common_words]
             all.append(text)
```

I want to delete certain words/stopword from either the variable "test", or later from the list "all" I put all the "text" variables from the iteration in.

I tried it like this, but this doesn't delete just words but also those letters if they exist in other words and the output is like 'd','f' for every word, and I want the format to stay the same, I just need those words in the common_words list deleted from the variable (or the list). How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a pythonic way for remove the punctuation from a test you can use `str.translate` method :

```
>>> "this is224$# a ths".translate(None,punctuation)
'this is224 a ths'
```

And for replace the words use `re.sub`,first create the regex with appending the pip (`|`) to words :

```
reg='|'.join(common_words)
new_text=re.sub(reg,'',text)
```

example :

```
>>> s="this is224$# a ths"
>>> import re
>>> w=['this','a']
>>> boundary_words=['\b{}\b'.format(i) for i in w]
>>> reg='|'.join(oundary_words)
>>> new_text=re.sub(reg,'',s).translate(None,punctuation)
>>> new_text
' is224  ths'
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but doing 
s="this is a good way to another place"
w=['this','a']
reg='|'.join() 
new_text=re.sub(reg,''s)

outputs "is good wy to nother plce" and removes "a" from other words too. How could I remove a only when it's alone?

Comment: @enderub you need to put your words in a word boundary! checkout the edt!